# Get file names which modified the particular string?

Tags: git

I need a list of files which added/removed the string "textXYZ" in the project history.

```
git log -S"testXYZ"
```

gives me the list of commits which introduce or remove an instance of the string "testXYZ".

Unfortunately each of those commits have more than 10 files.

How do I get a particular file(s) which introduce or remove the string in the commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `--stat` option:

```
git log -S"testXYZ" --stat
```

Or to get the diffs, add `--patch`.

Comment: Thanks dude. Is it possible to get the diffs also? Can you pls give an example on getting diffs using `--patch` option.

Comment: Just append the option to the end: `git log -S"testXYZ" --stat --patch`